# Where does the error “write downloadedfile: interrupted system call” come from?

Tags: arm, system-calls

All of a sudden I can’t get a program to complete its downloads because between 10% and 25% I get the error `write downloadedfile: interrupted system call`.

I have recently (long before the error begin to show up) updated the program but even restoring the previous version doesn’t fix it. I can’t reproduce the error in another computer (different architecture). If a file can reach 100%, I can redownload it without problems, while a problematic file returns the error in always different percentages, but is downloadable without problems in my other computer. I‘ve seen that after a reboot I can download every file, but after some days of uptime the errors return, in the meanwhile I run system updates.

I don’t think this is an error involving the program because there isn’t such a message in its source code and I’ve seen users facing it with bash scripts here in SO. Despite this, I can’t find further informations in the topic.

OS is Arch Linux ARM and the kernel recently switched from 4.19 to 5.4

Comment: You are not providing enough context, you should augment your question with a minimal, reproducible example. No images please, only code that can be copied/pasted

Comment: @Frant What code are you talking about? To reproduce the issue you would probably need an armv7 computer with my entire OS configuration

Comment: Exactly. There are only two options here: either your OS ' configuration'  is too specific to be reproduced on an Armv7-a system running the  Linux kernel 5.4, and you are on your own, or you can provide information that could make possible to reproduce the issue. By the way, how are you downloading ? C program using libcurl ? which support are you writing to ? SD card, hard drive ? what would be the last lines being displayed when running this command: `strace -f -v mysterious-polizi8-downloading-program` ?

Comment: @Frant With strace I discovered the error now occurs when I download to a mounted SMB share, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody seems to know where that error comes from, but it appears also with other programs, like `gitea dump --tempdir /mounted/smb/share`.

A workaround is using a local path instead of a remote one, and then moving the files there if necessary.

EDIT: This seems a [regression in recent kernels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599433/423407)